# Can not get getResponseCode

Tags: java, android, exception, urlconnection

```
public class SwitchRelays extends Activity {
LinearLayout layout1;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
String keyswitch = "http://192.168.2.200/key.php";
final Context context = this;
int respcode;
String codedisplay = "none";
static int responseCode = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.switches);
    String urlString = "http://192.168.2.200/android/get_sensors.php";
    new ProcessJSON().execute(urlString);
}

public  int coderesult(String urlString)  {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:passw".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseCode;
}

private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stream = null;
        String urlString = strings[0];
        HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
        stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);
        return stream;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            customButton(stream);
        }
    }
}

private void customButton(String stream) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(stream);
            JSONArray sensorsArray = reader.getJSONArray("sensors");
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearswitches);
            for (int j = 0; j <= sensorsArray.length()-1; j++) {
                JSONObject c = sensorsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String title = c.getString("key_title");
                final String pios = c.getString("key_pio");
                final String label = c.getString("key_label");
                int status = Integer.parseInt(pios);
                // Create Button
                final Switch btn = new Switch(this);
                //btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
                layout1.addView(btn,params);
                btn.setId(j + 1);
                btn.setText(title);
                btn.setChecked(true);
                if (status == 0)
                {btn.setChecked(false) ;}
                final int index = j;
                // Set click listener for button
                btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
                        if (bChecked) {
                            String urlstring = "http://192.168.2.200/key.php?key_label=termo3&key_pio=1";

                            respcode = coderesult(urlstring);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success:"+respcode,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            String urlstring = "http://192.168.2.200/key.php?key_label=termo3&key_pio=0";

                            respcode = coderesult(urlstring);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success:"+respcode,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

If I switch button, I Get : **"Unfortunately, project has stopped"**

in this line :

**responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();**

if call from

***respcode = coderesult(urlstring);***

On server side I get :

***"GET /key.php?key_label=termo3&key_pio=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/MASTER)***"

Error logs:

```
*FATAL EXCEPTION: main     Process: ru.smartsurgut.smart9, PID: 22820
                                                                   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
                                                                       at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
                                                                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
                                                                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
                                                                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:135)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
                                                                       at ru.smartsurgut.smart9.HTTPGet.GetHTTPResponse(HTTPGet.java:24)
                                                                       at ru.smartsurgut.smart9.SwitchRelays$1.onCheckedChanged(SwitchRelays.java:126)
                                                                       at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:156)
                                                                       at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:1070)
                                                                       at android.widget.Switch.toggle(Switch.java:1065)
                                                                       at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)*
```

Comment: The code is fine, but the android system does not allow you to use network operations on the main thread while in strict mode. You should use a AsyncTask to get the response code.

Comment: From where are you calling `coderesult` method?

Comment: respcode = coderesult(urlstring);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Async task for calling the codeResult() function

```
     AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {  
               codeResult()
           }
     });
```

you cant call Network requests on Mail Ui thread

Comment: How to switch button only after getting resultcode from server?

Comment: where are you calling this codeResult() function.. Can u update please?

Comment: it seems like both the codeResult() and customButton()'s listener is running on Main UI thread..  that will fix the error.. But cant figure out what your actual requirement is..